# Sign transaction with web3 wallet with flutter

Tags: flutter, metamask

I have a flutter DApp for which I want to deploy a contract.
The contract is created using the web3Dart library.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:web3dart/web3dart.dart';

class HTLCEthContract {
  final String apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545';

  Future<void> deployHTLC(
    String privateKey,
    String contractAddress,
    String recipientAddress,
    String hash,
    BigInt amount, {
    int lockTime = 720,
    int chainId = 1337,
  }) async {

    final privateKey = ''; // REPLACE WITH WALLET SIGNATURE

    final web3Client = Web3Client(apiUrl, Client());
    final credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(privateKey);

    final abiStringFile =
        await rootBundle.loadString('truffle/build/contracts/HTLC_ETH.json');
    final jsonAbi = jsonDecode(abiStringFile);
    final contract = DeployedContract(
      jsonAbi,
      EthereumAddress.fromHex(contractAddress),
    );

    final transaction = Transaction.callContract(
      contract: contract,
      function: contract.function('constructor'),
      parameters: [
        EthereumAddress.fromHex(recipientAddress),
        EthereumAddress.fromHex(contractAddress),
        EtherAmount.fromBigInt(EtherUnit.ether, amount),
        hash,
        BigInt.from(lockTime),
      ],
    );

    final transactionHash = await web3Client.sendTransaction(
      credentials,
      transaction,
      chainId: chainId,
    );
    final receipt = await web3Client.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);

    log('HTLC contract deployed at ${receipt!.contractAddress!.hex}');
  }
}
```

I'm having a problem signing the transaction because I don't want to manage the private key. So I'd like the transaction to be signed by a wallet (metamask for example) before being sent.

In my application, for the moment, I manage the connection to the web3 wallet via flutter_web3

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web3/flutter_web3.dart';

class MetaMaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const operatingChain = 4;

  String currentAddress = '';

  String account = '';

  int currentChain = -1;

  bool get isEnabled => ethereum != null;

  bool get isInOperatingChain => currentChain == operatingChain;

  bool get isConnected => isEnabled && currentAddress.isNotEmpty;

  final web3Provider = Web3Provider.fromEthereum(ethereum!);

  Future<void> connect() async {
    if (isEnabled) {
      final accs = await ethereum!.requestAccount();
      account = accs[0];

      if (accs.isNotEmpty) currentAddress = accs.first;

      currentChain = await ethereum!.getChainId();

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> changeChainId(int chainId) async {
    if (isEnabled && isConnected) {
      await ethereum!.walletSwitchChain(chainId);
    }
  }

  void clear() {
    currentAddress = '';
    currentChain = -1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void init() {
    if (isEnabled) {
      ethereum!.onAccountsChanged((accounts) {
        clear();
      });
      ethereum!.onChainChanged((chainId) {
        clear();
      });
      ethereum!.onDisconnect((error) {
        clear();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know how I can sign my transaction via the wallet?